# How do I simplify this expression?

Tags: sonarqube

```
var inventory = [
    { id: 1, name: 'apples', quantity: true },
    { id: 2, name: 'apples', quantity: false },
    { id: 3, name: 'cherries', quantity: true }
];
var result = inventory.find(inv => inv.id === 5) ? true: false;
```

Sonarqube is suggesting to simplify the expression below -

```
var result = inventory.find(inv => inv.id === 5) ? true: false;
```

I have no idea how to simplify it. Can anyone please help to simplify this ?
Sonarqube is suggesting that Boolean literals should not be redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sonarqube makes a remark that returning a direct boolean value based on condition is just obvious. Consider the following:

```
if (condition) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

or equivalent:

```
return (condition) ? true : false;
```

`condition` itself evaluates to `true` or `false`, so it's like saying 'if true then true, if false then false'. Therefore it is just enough to return result of the condition itself, like so:

```
return (condition);
```

Now your specific example makes implicit coalescing to a boolean value by using `find()` return value in a boolean context (implied by `?:` operator). Since `find()` returns `undefined` when the requested object is not found, your code makes use of [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value of `undefined` to resolve `?:` to true or false branch. It seems like you are interested in checking whether the value is present in the array, meaning whether `find()` returns something else than `undefined`, meaning:

```
var result = inventory.find(inv => inv.id === 5) !== undefined;
```